# Android Kotlin - get distance between View inside RecyclerView onBindViewHolder and top of the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

```
Log.d(tagg, "test1: " + holder.commentsLoading.top.toString())
holder.scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
    lastPosUpdate(meme.id, scrollY)
    Log.d(tagg, "test2: " + holder.commentsLoading.top.toString())
})

holder.textUserComments.setOnClickListener {
    Log.d(tagg, "test3: " + holder.commentsLoading.top.toString())
}
```

`test2` and `test3` are showing the same position no matter if I'm scrolling and change the actual position, `test1` returns 0, what the hell is wrong here!?

Comment: show adapter code

Comment: Please post your adapter code to better understanding.

Comment: I edited it, please check

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have that code inside onCreateViewHolder (which explains your problem). The mechanism behind recyclerView is that it only creates as many ViewHolder/Views as necessary to populate a full screen (approximately) - and then recycles the views. For that reason, a Viewholder will only be created once. test1 will be evaluated only once. On the contrary, since your listener gets called no matter how many times the view was recycled, you get the correct position.

Change this code:

> Log.d(tagg, "test1: " + holder.commentsLoading.top.toString())

to onBindViewHolder and your problem is solved.

Comment: It's not inside onCreateViewHolder but onBindViewHolder as the title says

Comment: maybe it would be better to describe what you want to do. It's not clear in the sample

Comment: I edited the title :D First the problem was that I couldn't get the distance to the top of the screen without the code being inside any listeners and then I realised that the View.top function only shows the distance to top of the parent instead of screen

Comment: Yes, commentsLoading is a view inside the itemView of your viewHolder, so its top position is not relative to the recyclerview. So, your problem is solved then ?